# How to make hollow box with increasing and decreasing number at the side?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have attempted a java program that includes hollow in the middle and numbers decrease and increase at the sides based on user's input.
Let say the user's input is 4, so the output should be like this:-

```
1 2 3 4
2     3
3     2
4 3 2 1
```

and i managed to do it until its like this:-

```
1 2 3 4 
2
3
4 3 2 1
```

by using this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise2 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter an integer >0 and <21: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    { 
        System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
    }  
    System.out.println();

    for (int j = 1; j < num-1; j++)
    {
        System.out.println((j+1) + " ");
    }       
 // for (int j = num-1; j > 1; j--)
 // {
 //    System.out.print(j + " ");
 // }
    for (int j = num; j > 0; j--)
    {
        System.out.print((j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();



    if (num > 21 || num < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong number range");
    }
 }
}
```

I dont know how to do the other side of it to become 4 3 2 1 downwards. I tried uncommenting the commented codes and it gave 3 2 which is what i wanted but not in a straight line. I dont know where my error is. And i dont how to insert blank space (System.out.print("  ")) so that the hollow is actually something printed, not just blank.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.   Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please advise me"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: @JimGarrison Ive read the links. Does that mean i can only ask questions that other people might search for it too? Thats what ive concluded based on what ive read on the links and peoples' comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print((j + 1) + " ");
            } else if (i == num-1) {
                System.out.print((num - j) + " ");
            } else if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            } else if (j == num-1) {
                System.out.print((num - i) + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```